# Moving data between tables in different tables in postgreSQL on other column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, data-migration

I have a table in a schema called fs in a postgreSQl database that looks like this:

```
id  cik    tf_dict_phrase  factset_entity_id  key_name 
1   738076                 000BFD-E           raw_text/738076_2005-08-05_10-K
2   738076                 000BFD-E           raw_text/738076_2006-08-11_10-K
3   738076                 000BFD-E           raw_text/738076_2007-07-31_10-K
```

And I have another table in the public shema which looks like this:

```
id  tokenized  key_name
1   {"a":1...} 1000180_2005-03-18_10-K
2   {"b":1...} raw_text/1004980_2007-02-22_10-K
3   {"%":1...} raw_text/1004980_2006-02-17_10-K
```

I would like to fill in the tf_dict_phrase column in the first table with the data in the tokenized column from the second table based on key_name matching.

Do I need to turn key_name into a foreign key? Thank you!

The id's are autogenerated in each table, so they will not match necessarily.

Update: I tried this with no luck

```
UPDATE ten_k_with_public
SET    tf_dict_phrases = public.raw_document.raw_data
FROM   public.raw_document
WHERE  fs.ten_k_with_public.key_name = public.raw_document.key_name
```

Comment: Do you try to prefix the table names with the schema name? Or do you set search_path?

Comment: I updated the question to include the prefixes I used. I now get this error when I run the cod above `[54000] ERROR: index row requires 177408 bytes, maximum size is 8191`

Comment: `tf_dict_phrases = public.raw_document.raw_data` Both these columnnames do not exist in your table definitions. Please be consistent when renaming things.

Comment: Sorry @wildplasser, I don't understand the problem or how to fix it (I am very new to SQL). Could you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: @GrahamStreich thats the answer. You cant store big values in fields that are primary keys o unique keys. See https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/162867790909192247o2d883011wc63a4dbcb99402d3%40mail.gmail.com

Comment: thanks @EmilioPlatzer, but the link to hashing functions in that answer seems to have been replaced...any code examples would be much appreciated! thanks again.